# Can't find files deleted from /var/www/

Tags: permissions, apache2, data-recovery, trash

I was working on some files located inside my Apache's /var/www/html/ and accidentally deleted them. I did this via right-click "Move to Trash".

However, looking at my trash folder, they aren't there.

Apparently the owner of "html" folder is root, which I found out by doing ls- l inside "www":

```
drwxrwxrwx 7 root root 4096 may  6 13:34 html
```

How can I recover these files? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking further into this, I actually only have the "Delete" option in my right-click menu for items inside "html". In other folders I do have "Move to trash" instead of "Delete".
So how do I recover files deleted this way? I would have expected them to be in the Trash regardless, since it doesn't even offer a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on "regular" Ubuntu (not Xubuntu, Kubuntu, etc) you could try running

```
gksudo nautilus
```

in a terminal or launcher.

That will open the file manager with root privileges, and you can check Root's trash from there.

Also check to see if there are any hidden folders within /var/www/html/ -- Nautilus should have an option called "View Hidden Files" that could potentially reveal a `.Trash` or `.Trash-1000` directory.

However, if your files are not there, I'm afraid that (barring more-complex file-recovery methods) you're out of luck, my friend... consider this a good opportunity to re-evaluate your backup strategy.

Please let me know if this answer was helpful or if you have any questions.

--Nick

Comment: Nick, thanks for your comment. I'm able to access root trash but there's still nothing in there. I will definitely rethink my backup strategy. What I am most surprised about this tragedy is that a simple "right-click delete" purges files beyond recovery (at least the easy ways). Cheers.

Comment: @MdE that's what the *Delete* option does. It deletes files (the name is kinda descriptive). It is different from *Move to trash* for this reason. One should be very careful about deleting stuff, especially while running as `root`.